# deleting data sent to thread in FLTK using c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, fltk

I'm performing a long task, implemented in some function, in a new thread (i.e. not the main GUI thread) in FLTK (in C++).

I achieve this with a callback function that in turn creates the thread so that I have something of the form

```
void callback(Fl_Widget* widget,void* passed_data){

data_type* data = new data_type;

data->value = x; //populate data structure to send to function

fl_create_thread(thread1,function,data);

}
```

where fl_create_thread (at least for my purposes) is just using pthread_create meaning the data variable is passed as a void pointer and so 'function' takes a void pointer too.

I realised that this would actually create a memory leak as I don't delete 'data':
I can't delete it after the line with fl_create_thread as the thread hasn't necessarily (or ever) finished running. I have tried deleting the pointer at the end of 'function' but this raises two issues

1) Deleting a void pointer is undefined and so I am getting warnings to that effect.

2) This almost defeats the point of using a function: is there a better general coding practice?

Can anyone tell me how I should approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Deleting a void pointer is undefined and so I am getting warnings
>   to that effect.

You're probably a casting to the proper type at the very beginning of your function (or you should in order to meaningfully use the parameter). Delete that pointer instead of the `void *` parameter and you will not get a warning.

> 2) This almost defeats the point of using a function: is there a
>   better general coding practice?

Not sure I see your point. This thread interface (pthread) is very c-like, so it has to resort to void pointers in order to pass arbitrary data. You can you look at [C++ thread interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) for a more C++ way of defining what to execute and with what parameters

With memory you should always have clear the ownership of allocated memory. This approach *transfers* the ownership to the just created thread.

Comment: You're right, I am casting to the datatype I need. To clarify, is it safe and correct (avoiding the memory leak) to, within 'function', perform (where data is the void_ptr passed the function in the original question)

data_type* ptr = (data_type*) data;
delete ptr;

Other than that, I guess I meant that it would be nice to be able to  write a function so that it could be ignorant as to whether it was being called using pass by reference, or by using variables on the heap or in a thread etc. (ie not worry about the memory leak possibility inside itself). May look into std::thread. Thanks.